# How to order Descending to workflow history via programatically in sitecore

Tags: workflow

How can I sort the workflow history on time?
I got the workflow and workflow history programmatically, but I cannot order by date descending?

Get Workflow and History:

```
Sitecore.Workflows.WorkflowEvent[] workflowHistory = master.WorkflowProvider.GetWorkflow(workFlowItem).GetHistory(workFlowItem);
foreach (Sitecore.Workflows.WorkflowEvent work in workflowHistory)
{
  var comments += work.CommentFields["Comments"]
}
```

Kindly Assist,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sitecore.Workflows.WorkflowEvent[] workflowHistory = master.WorkflowProvider.GetWorkflow(workFlowItem).GetHistory(workFlowItem);
foreach (Sitecore.Workflows.WorkflowEvent work in workflowHistory.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)) 
{ 
  var comments += work.CommentFields["Comments"] 
}
```